# How can I create a contourf plot of a known value between already known vertices?

Tags: python, plot, contourf

I am trying to visualize the distribution of a Mach number in an underexpanded jet nozzle. I have calculated the Mach numbers with the aid of the Method of characteristics. I have also calculated the intersection points of the characteristics. Therefore, I have the vertices of the polygons and the Mach numbers that I need to visualize in each polygon. How should I proceed?

I tried contourf, but it expects meshgrid (2D) data

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.